# Laravel 8 - Setting a cookie in response not working

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, httpresponse

I'm using Laravel 8 for my backend and I'm trying to store my auth token in a cookie.
I want to set that cookie in my controller response, and I'm trying this way:

```
return response()->cookie('token', $tokenResult->accessToken, 10000);
```

The problem here is that Laravel can not find cookie method.
According to Laravel 8 documentation, cookie() is a method from ResponseTrait, but Laravel is trying to get it from Macroable trait:

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory: :cookie does not exist. in file /var/www/html/t2t-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php
```

How could I solve this issue? Thank you.

P.S.
It seems to work if I add a parameter to response() like this:

```
return response('Hello World')->cookie('token', $tokenResult->accessToken, 10000);
```

But I need a JSON response instead of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use cookie on a new \Illuminate\Http\Response

```
$response = new \Illuminate\Http\Response();
return $response->cookie("name","value",360);
```

Comment: It throws the same exception: withCookie does not exist in Macroable.

Comment: @RubénEsteban just updated the answer, this time i tested with no errors. hope it solves your problem